How does the UK reconcile collecting statistics on diversity with the restrictions on recruitment questions under the Equalities Act?
This question on The Workplace asks about intrusive questions during a job interview.
My initial thoughts were that these sorts of questions concerning religion, gender, class etc. were forbidden by the Equalities Act 2010.  However I believe there have been a number of diversity reporting initiatives that would seem to require answers to those sort of questions.
I've trawled the internet but the only information I can find are articles by third parties such as recruitment agencies, ACAS etc.
So what questions are banned during recruitment, and how are diversity statistics collected by employers within those restrictions?

it’s unwise, but not illegal
The Equality Act makes it illegal to discriminate on the basis of a protected class, but it doesn’t make it illegal to ask an individual if they are in a protected class.
However, it’s unwise because it raises the obvious question of “Since it’s not relevant to the job, why do you want to know?” And the answer might just be “In order to do illegal discrimination.”
An employer who doesn’t ask and doesn’t know is in a better position to defend an anti-discrimination claim than one who does. Perhaps. However, an employer who ‘just happens’ to end up with a workforce that is overwhelmingly white, male, and between the ages of 25 and 40, might want to know that even if it’s not the result of active discrimination.

+1  And how does this fit with collecting information concerning diversity?  I believe companies have to provide data about their gender pay gap, are they under any other legal obligations?
